# passing nginx a relative filename via -c flag

Tags: nginx

nginx accepts an argument via command line to specify the location of a config file:

```
-c filename   : set configuration file
```

For my use case, `filename` must be a path relative to the current working directory, but nginx always seems to interpret `filename` relative to its install location:

```
$ nginx -c nginx.conf
=> nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.1/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Is it even possible to pass nginx a cwd-relative path for `filename`? "No" is an acceptable answer.

Comment: Have you tried "./nginx.conf"?  Also, it might be strictly impossible for security reasons

Comment: @Wug: that's what I suspect, too. (`nginx -c ./nginx.conf` gives the same error)

Comment: You can use `nginx -c $PWD/nginx.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its relative to `--prefix` that was passed to `configure` during the configure & compilation, which in most cases is likely `/usr` so its relative to that.

For example on my machine:

`$ nginx -V` yields:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.2.6
built by gcc 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr --with-http_ssl_module ... other stuff...
```

Notice `--prefix=/usr`, so this is your base path that `-c` is relative to.

Thus:

`$ nginx -t -c nginx.conf`

Fails with:

```
$ nginx -t -c nginx.conf
nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

And its clear that nginx is looking relative to the value of `--prefix`

Comment: Thanks. So is it true to say that nginx simply can't accept pathnames relative to the current working directory?

Comment: @pje yes, this appears to be the case.